# Outlook 2016 script

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, script

I am looking to create a rule to remove a specific sentence from every incoming email in Outlook 2016.  The sentence is static and never changes but I don't want it in the body of the email.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Script to Dynamically Change Subject Line on Incoming Emails for Outlook 2013](https://superuser.com/questions/1016279/vba-script-to-dynamically-change-subject-line-on-incoming-emails-for-outlook-201)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @HackSlash I've gone as far as to figure out how to enable the developers tab in Outlook 2016 and get to the VB6 console.  Unfortunately I am not proficient in the language to code it.  The text I am looking to remove from the body (not subject) is a disclaimer stamped from the mail server.

Comment: You are going to need to understand VBA and specifically outlook event handling in VBA. 
Please read this: https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask